# Bachelor's in Mathematics or Bachelor of Mathematics?

Tags: word-usage

What's the correct name of the degree?

Bachelor's in Mathematics or Bachelor of Mathematics?

Addendum: If a document says: The University... grants the degree of: ... Which one would be correct?

Answer (score 2):

I can’t speak for other countries, but in general, in the United States, a college or university will award a *Bachelor of Science* degree with a major concentration of Mathematics. This is generally shortened in speech and informal writing as “a Bachelor's in Mathematics”, or even shorter and even more colloquial as “a Bach [*pronounced as if it were **batch***] in Math”.

Some subjects will result in the award of a *Bachelor of Arts* degree instead, but the colloquial usage is the same, and a very few subjects, such as Business Administration, Public Administration, and Law, have subject-specfic degrees (e.g., *Bachelor of Business Administration*).

Comment: The year I graduated, my college was insisting on awarding the degrees in Latin, so my B.Sc.C.S (Bachelor of Science in Computer Science) is "really" a B.G.C.S (Baccalaureos Gradus in Computatrum Scientia).

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick image search for "bachelor certificate". Among the first 50 hits or so, 48 read, "*Bachelor **of** [Whatever]*". The [other](http://www.diploma-degree.com/Degree/700-1634-Bachelor%27s%20degree%20certificate.jpg) [two](http://www.diploma-degree.com/Degree/700-1617-Bachelor+s+degree+certificate.jpg) appear to me to be fake certificates.

Noteworthy: None of them used the word "grants". They mostly used various forms of "admit" and "confer".

Also: In casual speech, it's natural to say, *"a Bachelor's **in** Mathematics"*, even though that's not what appears on a certificate.